# In Hinduism, what is an astral body?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, mind-body, souls, hinduism

As per Hindu philosophy, there are three things - Body, Mind and Soul. Sometimes we come across this term "Astral Body."
I read in a book:

> "When doing meditation, deeply into it, our astral body separates from us and moves freely into the ether."

This is very confusing to understand intellectually. Apart from the three things as mentioned above, what is this?

Comment: Could you perhaps tell us what book, and maybe specify your question a little further in general? I'm not an expert but simply saying there are three "things" and that "sometimes we come across this term" is very vague. Some more context (more instances of the phrase "astral body," for example) would be very helpful.

Comment: I'm going to put this question on hold until we can get some context for the question. As of 20 seconds ago our answers were "I don't know what you are talking about", "I'm not sure what you are talking about" and some unreferenced information about astral bodies in general (as opposed to how they specifically relate to Hinduism); this is telling and an indication that the question needs to be improved first.

Comment: @SaiKrishna Your body is just your interface and subtle/astral body is your soul energy (your light body). Like computer which can't work without the energy. I believe the question is more suitable on [Paranormal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/84880/paranormal) proposal.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are asking about (although I'm not sure):

The [astral body](http://www.sivanandaonline.org/public_html/?cmd=displaysection&section_id=774) (Sukshma sarira) in one bit of [Vedanta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedanta) thought [carries your soul](http://hinduism.iskcon.org/concepts/102.htm).

> The Subtle Body
>
> Disciple: What is the composition of the subtle body?
>
> Guru: The subtle body is composed of nineteen principles (Tattvas), viz., five Jnana Indriyas or organs of knowledge, five Karma Indriyas or organs of action, five Pranas or vital airs, Manas or mind, Buddhi or intellect, Chitta or the subconscious and Ahamkara or the ego. It is a means of enjoying pleasure and pain.
>
> Disciple: When will this subtle body get dissolved?
>
> Guru: It gets dissolved in Videha Mukti or disembodied Liberation.

[Videha Mukti](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Videha_mukti) / [Liberaton](http://hinduism.iskcon.org/concepts/106.htm) ends [samsara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sa%E1%B9%83s%C4%81ra#Sams.C4.81ra_in_Hinduism).

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtle_body#Hinduism

Answer (score 0):

The **astral body** is simply the parts of you which are not completely connected to your physicality because you have not integrated all the centers of your body, mind, and spirit together.  It's as simple as that, but...

What's not so simple is that putting a name on something so ephemeral actually disassociates a part of you, so you're not necessarily better off with any understanding of it at all.

Comment: The question is asking about very esoteric matters which are held by subjective knowledge.  Other reliable sources can be found in Buddhist temples in Asia.